# Trouble with function inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, header, parameter-passing

I have 3 files 2 header files and one .CPP file

the header file code
STX.H

```
/ search for item in the list and delete it if found 
void SeqList::Delete(const DataType& item)
```

I am trying to pass a last name variable to it from the Employee.CPP file

```
void SeqList::Delete(const DataType& item)
{
    lastname = item;
}
```

*the error in the .CPP is lastname is undefined.*

this is what the header file looks like for employee

```
class Employee
{
private:
    string lastname;

public:
    void SeqList::Delete(const DataType& item);
```

the error in this class is "qualifier must be base class of "Employee"

how do I solve this.

I'm still trying to grasp exactly how to inherit things so bear with me.

Comment: If the `Delete` function is not e member of the `Employee` class, why do you declare it in the `Employee` class? And where (if anywhere) is `lastname` declared? And can you please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: i think that should do it i thought that was minimal enough.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your class `Employee` the `lasname` is `private`:  only  member functions of Employee can access it.

Then you have a syntax problem with the qualifier `SeqList::`in your class definition:

```
class Employee
{
...
public:
    void SeqList::Delete(const DataType& item);   //oops !! 
...
};
```

If `Delete()` is a memeber function of `Employee`, just remove the qualifier.

If `Delete()` is not a member of `Employee`, but should be a memeber of another class (i.e.  `SeqList`), then you have defined your function in the wrong place.  You have to declare it in the SeqList class.  But in this case you'll have a problem with `lastname` :  SeqList member functions won't have access to it unless you make it public.